# How to cash ACH vouchers to my French account without paying more banking fees than sending a postal package containing cash?

Tags: check, international-transfer, fees, foreign-income, ach

I worked for a company based in the United States as part of a non-commercial activity (I mean the income is not taxable to the IRS and thus I can’t get an itin or ssn in order to open a bank account). I need to receive several ach vouchers from them.

I’m currently in France and I have no plan to get a visa to come to the United States in the current decade.

The company only pays through regular ACH voucher over usps: they use an automated system. It’s not possible to negotiate anything on the payment method. I can’t even ask to merge the vouchers in order to pay less in fees.

It’s a reputable company. It used to be a Hewlett Packard subsidiary for more than 10 years and they acted like this too when they were still part of hp.

On the other hand, I need to relay the voucher to a swift transfer in usd with my name as sender with swift details to an account with an iban number.

Comment: Could you explain what a USD voucher is? Ive never heard of one and a quick google does nothing

Comment: @Vality I meant ᴀᴄʜ vouchers in ᴜꜱᴅ indeed. Which means vouchers without ɪʙᴀɴ numbers nor ꜱᴡɪꜰᴛ.

Comment: Oh, I see. I will note however, you don't actually need an SSN to open a bank account. I currently do have one but long before I did I was able to open a Wells Fargo account with just my (foreign) passport info.

Comment: @Vality that’s the second part of the question : an affordable bank. And not only Well Fargo is expensive but they paid a $1000000000 fine for customer fees abuse. I fear a ꜱꜱɴ is better help in that case. The alternative is to explore the full list of the ꜰᴅɪᴄ by going on each website in order to see rates.

Comment: Please don't misunderstand, I wasn't suggesting you use Wells Fargo, I stopped using them a long time ago myself. I am merely saying your suggestion that you must have an SSN or ITIN to have a bank account is incorrect, and was backing up my statement by mentioning a specific account I was able to open. I wont go into the bank I use now as I feel like that would be advertising. But there are several who are cheap and good.

Comment: @Vality I found banks with free debit card along free checking account along providing cashing‑in vouchers for less than $15 per check but they either require to come locally at agency or ave an ꜱꜱɴ. Though maybe a bank like this which accept strangers exists *(I just didn’t found it)*.

Comment: What is an "ACH voucher"? Googling that term in quotes only gives me 264 results, so I suspect you're still using the wrong term...

Comment: @Cody International vouchers have an ɪʙᴀɴ number. ᴀᴄʜ vouchers have ᴀᴄʜ account numbers and one of those numbers involve the location code of the bank in the United States so that a United States Bank account is required for cashing in the voucher (because the transaction use input and output account).

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by an "ACH voucher". Do you mean a check/cheque?

Comment: @Cody [well](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/voucher).

Comment: I think this is the missing bit of information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_clearing_house. "Electronic check" probably comes closest.

Comment: I know what ACH is. I know what a voucher is. I don’t know what an “ACH voucher” is. Seriously, google it: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ach+voucher%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us&client=safari its not a common term.

Comment: And @Marianne013, they specifically said “over usps”, which is why my best guess is that they’re just talking about a regular paper check. I asked but they didn’t answer.

Comment: Second best guess is that they have a form that’s asking for account and routing number which would then be used to initiate an ACH transfer.

Comment: @Cody yes sent by mail. The check can only be used with the ACH system.

Answer (score 0):

> I can’t get an itin or ssn in order to open a bank account

You don't need an SSN or an ITIN to open a bank account. [Several commenters on this post](https://www.doctorofcredit.com/bankscredit-unions-allow-open-deposit-account-without-ssn/#comment-360192) share their experiences doing so at specific banks. That said, it seems like most of them also had to open these accounts in person, which you said you're not willing to do.

If you have a trusted friend in the USA, you could [sign the checks over to them](https://www.thebalance.com/instructions-and-problems-with-signing-a-check-over-315318) to cash into their own accounts and then transfer to you.

Other than that, unless any of your conditions change, I think you're stuck paying your bank's fees.

Comment: Do you realize there’s more than 2000$ for coming into the ᴜꜱᴀ from where I live (not to mention this wouldn’t be work time) ? I also know such persons which can help me but they won’t offer me to pay for their income tax. **When you bring a ᴀᴄʜ  check at a French bank they will tell you it’s Ok, and 5 months later that they are still working at validating the cheque and 8 to 12 months later than you never deposited such type of paper** so a United States bank account is required. And it appears Wells Fargo now require to come at branch. Though I recognize this can’t work with Swiss Franc.

Comment: So I’m not stuck at paying fees, but I’m stuck at [getting robbered](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/103670).

Comment: The more I think about this, the more it seems like a problem between you and the payer. If they're not willing to pay you in a way that's convenient for you, maybe they're not worth working for.

Comment: I have a similar problem with Google so I don’t think it’s about working with. I saw hundreds banks which offers fee free wire transfers and no fees on international debit card transactions like simple.com equitybank and UnitedNationsFCU and bank.bank and Charles Schwab Bank. So having a cheap bank is easy if you live in the United States as none of those banks accept non resident aliens without a ꜱꜱɴ and without coming at a branch. as I explained everything would had been simple if Hillary Clinton got elected instead of Donald Trump. I could do like most undocumented latinos did.

Comment: those payment practices (of requiring a payment method instead of paypal or Western Union) also preclude 2016 presidential election. So this wasn’t a problem before. A bank comparator for undocumented foreigners would be something great to create. Through there’s might be a possibility in my case : https://money.stackexchange.com/q/103700